# How to set margin for whole document and all sections by apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I want to edit whole document page margin by apache-poi and I want all sections to be changed. This is my code:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("template.docx"));
CTSectPr sectPr = docx.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(1200L));
pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(500L));
pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(800L));
pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
docx.write(new FileOutputStream("test2.docx"));
```

But only the latest section is changed, not all sections and not whole document.
What should I do to change all sections' margin and whole document's margin?

Comment: @Punit Your edit introduced useless markdown and a new mistake; in the future please try to fix *all* issues in a post when editing and double-check if all changes are correct. OP: Please only accept edits that actually make your post better.

Comment: You are right. I accepted edits by mistake and I became regretted after that. Thank you.  @Baum mit Augen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the document is separated into sections then the `SectPr`s for the first sections are in `PPr` elements within the paragraphs which are the section separators. Only the `SectPr` for the last section is directly within the `Body`. So we need looping through all paragraphs to get all `SectPr`s.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordGetAllSectPr {

 public static List<CTSectPr> getAllSectPr(XWPFDocument document) {
  List<CTSectPr> allSectPr = new ArrayList<>();
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() != null && paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr() != null) {
    allSectPr.add(paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr());
   }
  }
  allSectPr.add(document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr());
  return allSectPr;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("template.docx"));

  List<CTSectPr> allSectPr = getAllSectPr(docx);
System.out.println(allSectPr.size());

  for (CTSectPr sectPr : allSectPr) {
   CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
   pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(1200L));
   pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(500L));
   pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(800L));
   pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
  }

  docx.write(new FileOutputStream("test2.docx"));
  docx.close();
 }

}
```